# Spring along with Swing

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-boot

I'm using Spring along with Swing. At the click of a Button the following code block is being called.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProcessFile {

    public String startProcess() {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ProcessFile.class);
        ReadFile readFile = context.getBean(ReadFile.class);
        return readFile.getData();
    }

}
```

But am just wondering if I click that multiple times then will multiple Spring context be created or is there some other issues. My UI has just a Single JPanel to select a file and call this startProcess method which does many tasks. Or will the SpringContext be destroyed when the following code block execution finishes?

Answer (score 0):

I think about your health you should only have a spring application context in your application :)

For this you can implement a CommandLineRunner and display the Swing application:

```
@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    /**
     * the JFrame to be displayed.
     */
    @Autowired
    private DemoFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        /* display the form using the AWT EventQueue */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
       });
    }

}



@Component
public class DemoFrame extends JFrame{
    // other code here....

    @Autowired
    ReadFile readFile;

    public String startProcess() {
        return readFile.getData();
    }

    // other code here....
}
```